# Find dominant color of a video

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science

on Stackoverflow I have found many posts about how to find the prevalent color of an image in python. However, I have not found anything about videos. Maybe because it could be possible to process each frame, but I was wondering if there is any easier method. In particular, I would like to study the dominant color of a whole movie.
Thank you a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A video consists of multiple frames(images). If you would like to get the dominant color, you should get it per image and merge your results.